# How to debug into response.addCookie(...)?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, servlets, jboss, struts

i have a struts application in a jboss server. i would like to be able to debug into *response.addCookie(...)* when working from Eclipse.

what do I have to do to be able to press Step Into from Eclipse, in a Struts action, when its doing *response.addCookie(...)* ?

I did try to press Step into and it sayd "Source not found". Then I pressed the "Edit source lookup path..." button, choose "Add source", "External Archive" and pointed to the downloaded source code of JBoss "jboss-4.2.3.GA-src.tar.gz"

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on `HttpServletResponse#addCookie()`.

If your concrete problem is that you don't have the source code, you need to download it for the servletcontainer in question first (if it is open source, JBoss is) and then include it in Eclipse.

Comment: So your concrete problem is that you don't know how to include source in Eclipse?

Comment: @BalusC, after running `response.addCookie(cookie);`, how can I know if add cookie success?